# What's the ratio of saturated to unsaturated fatty acids in human cell membrane?

Tags: molecular-biology, human-physiology, cell-membrane

It's well established that the fluidity of a cell is largely dependent upon the ratio of saturated to unsaturated fatty acids that exist within the membrane, but, what exactly are the values for this ratio?

Given that cells maintain a constant degree of fluidity (assuming constant environmental conditions), I would think this ratio could be properly defined.

I've tried looking through several molecular biology books and I Googled for about 30 minutes, but nothing..

Can anyone provide this ratio, or, explain why it's not obtainable?

Comment: [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005273612000156) provides some data for rats.

Comment: i never use Google for specific scientific queries. i always use PubMed: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed

Comment: @MartinKlvana Google scholar is a very good alternative to PubMed.